# How can I export a Wikipedia article with slash in name via special:export using curl/wget on Windows

Tags: windows, curl, mediawiki, wget, wikipedia

i tried to download a list of files via special:export.
This works fine, as long as there no slash  or exotic chars in the name.

```
   Österreichischer_Fußball-Cup_2013/14 --> Slash after 2013 tried to replace slash with %2F did not work
   İlhan_ Cihaner --> not in Latin


   @echo off
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   for /f %%l in (wikipedia.test) do (
       curl -O http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezial:Exportieren/"%%l"
   )
```

I tried already to urlencode (only the articlename) via [Sed](http://gimi.name/snippets/urlencode-and-urldecode-for-bash-scripting-using-sed/) , but this did'nt work.
Tried also

```
   @echo off
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   for /f %%l in (wikipedia.test) do (
       curl  --data-urlencode "&pages=%%l&offset=1&action=submit" http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export -o %%l.xml
   )
```

In the manual of curl i did not find a hint...

Comment: Nitpick, but İ is perfectly latin, though not in the *ISO basic* subset. Now, what happens when have `İ` or `/` in a page name? Any error message to share?

Comment: there is no errormessage. The page is missing  in the result (XML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'pages' parameter to Special:Export, like so:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezial:Exportieren?pages=%C3%96sterreichischer_Fu%C3%9Fball-Cup_2013/14